# how to insert an image to database using ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

so i have a form update but my problem is i cant save my image into my database only the file path..

here is my code.

```
<form action="" id="update_profile" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <img class="img-responsive" id="profile_image" name="profile_image" src=""/>
     <input class="btn-success" type="file" name="image" id="image" onchange="loadFile(event)">
   </div>
     <input type="text" id="users_lastname" name="users_lastname" class="form-control" value="">
</form>
```

from the form update i use ajax to display the data from my database to the form fields..

```
   $.ajax({
          url:'../ajax/getprofile.php',
          type:'POST',
          data:{userid:user},
          dataType:'JSON',
          success: function(result){
          $('#profile_image').attr('src',result.profile_image);  
          $('#users_lastname').val(result.users_firstname);
          },
          error:function(status){

          }
      });

$('#update_profile').submit(function(){
     var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
      url: '../ajax/update_profile.php',
      type:'POST',
      data: formData,
      dataType: 'JSON',
      contentType: false,
      cache: false, 
      processData:false,
      success:function(result){
        console.log(result);
      },
      error:function(status){
        // console.log(status.responseText);
      }
    });
});
```

and use another ajax for submitting the form so basically what happens is from the  `<img src="../assets/img/faces/avatar.jpg">` this is where i display my image from my db. and when i click the `<input class="btn-success" type="file" name="image" id="image" onchange="loadFile(event)">` `<img src="../assets/img/faces/koala.jpg">` will change its value...

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
$users_lastname = $_POST['users_lastname'];
$profile_image = $_POST['profile_image'];

$imgFile = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmp_dir = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$imgSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];
}
if($imgFile)
        {
            $upload_dir = '../assets/img/faces/'; // upload directory   
            $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension
            $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions
            $userpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;
            if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions))
            {           
                if($imgSize < 2000000)
                {
                    // unlink($upload_dir.$_SESSION['image']);
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userpic);
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<script>
                            alert("Sorry, your file is too large it should be less then 2MB");
                          </script>';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<script>
                            alert("Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.");
                      </script>';       
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            $userpic = $imgs; // old image from database
            $userpic = substr($userpic,20);
        }
if(!isset($errMSG))
        {

            $path = '../assets/img/faces/'. $userpic;

            $action= 'Updated his/her information'; 
            $logs= $log->insertLogs($usernm,$action);

          $res = $users->Userupdated($user,$users_firstname,$users_lastname,$users_email);

        $data = $users->updateUserdetail($user,$path,$profile_contact,$profile_address,$profile_department,$profile_specialization,$profile_aboutme);
}
else{
        $errMSG = "Sorry Data Could Not Updated !";
        }
```

but when i tried to upload without replacing the image from the src. what happens is it only uploads the location path not the exact image. also when i replace the image it only uploads the location path.. i dont know if this is the correct approach for getting the `src image` any idea for this?

Comment: An image (img tag)  is not a form element. You need to use a file input to upload the image.

Comment: yeah im using input file.. but my problem is saying i already have an image on my db.. and i display it on `<img src=" ">` what i wanted to do is what if i only wanted to update my information and not my image?..what suppose to happen is that it will still upload the image with the same filepath and image on my db..like reloading nothing will happens on the image if i only wanted to update my info.

Comment: is there any better approach to do this??.. i already fix the problem on upload the new image.. the only problem i got now is if i only wanted my information to be update only the info will be upadated not my image but on my code it also uploads the image what where my problem goes cuz what happens is only the path is being uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I used this in one of my proect:

```
var form = $("#update_profile").get(0); 
        e.preventDefault(); //keeps the form from behaving like a normal (non-ajax) html form

        $.ajax({
            url: '../ajax/update_profile.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: new FormData(form),
            dataType: 'json',
            mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (response) {


            },
            error: function (data) {

            }
        });
```